# Multi-module maven project - use a module just as a dependency

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

The project consists of multiple Maven modules using Spring. One of the modules, `DependencyService`, contains Java classes (models) that I want to reuse in `Backend1` and `Backend2` without duplicating code. However, due to some Docker-related requirements, I cannot compile and run the `DependencyService` module directly from Eclipse. Therefore, I need a way to include the classes from `DependencyService` in `Backend1` and `Backend2` without actually compiling the entire DependencyService module.

So, how can I include the classes from `DependencyService` in `Backend1` and `Backend2` for reuse, without actually compiling the entire `DependencyService` module? This is because the `DependencyService` module requires additional setup with Docker, preventing it from being compiled directly in Eclipse.

**Project structure:**

```
MainFolder
 |
 --MainApplication
      |
      --Backend1
          |
           --pom.xml
      |
      --Backend2
          |
          --pom.xml
 |
 --DependencyService
      |
      --someModelsAreInHere
      |
      --pom.xml
 |
 --pom.xml
```

**MainFolder Pom**

```
<!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</parent>
<modules><module>Backend1</module><module>Backend2</module></modules>
...
<!-- root pom settings -->
<groupId>GROUP</groupId>
<artifactId>MainProject</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>MainProjectName</name>
...
<!-- Manages Dependencies -->
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>      
        <dependency>  <!-- Import the dependency here -->
            <groupId>GROUP.MainProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>DependencyService</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency.service.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
... </project>
```

**Backend1** as an example,Backend1, Backend2 and DependencyService's pom.xml look very similar.

```
<!-- Inherit defaults from MainFolder -->
<parent>
    <artifactId>MainProject</artifactId>
    <groupId>GROUP</groupId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>


<!-- data-processor pom settings -->
<groupId>GROUP</groupId>
<artifactId>backend1</artifactId>
<name>Backend1Name</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>${revision}</version>

    <!-- Add required dependencies -->
<dependencies>    
    <!--  include DependencyService here but JUST for the classes, not for compiling! -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>GROUP.MainProject</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependencyService</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: If you define a dependency that means it will become part of the classpath...

Comment: Mhh, isn't there some solution? My only goal is to use those classes (from DependencyService) in the other directories. Isn't that possible somehow? It would also be okay for me to leave this out of dependency but than I also don't know how to use those classes

Comment: To be honest I don't understand for what purpose you would like to use classes but not via classpath? Please elaborate more in detail why/how you are using them...

Comment: Sure, no problem. The `DependencyService` was given by my supervisor (university). This service provides an api to a mysql database and the classes for the database (e.g. a "customer"-class with variables like name, age, ...). (At least I'm) not able to let this service run in eclipse, because we first create a docker container which runs the database and then another one which runs the api. And from my point of view this process is not possible in eclipse. Thats the main reason, why I only want to use those classes. I have to access the api, get data from those classes and process them :)

Comment: Addition: The main reason is for this is, that if I try to run the given service I'll get an error message like "failed to determine a suitable driver class, If you want an embedded database please putt itt on the classpath, ...". And I googled a bit for this error and then thought that it would be easier to just use the classes without adding the whole thing to the class path. As I said it was given so there is no real need to compile it each time, I basically just want to grab the data :D

Comment: You can exclude your dependency for certain maven goals. Please check below links if that can help you - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/exclude-dependencies-from-dependency-analysis.html    https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: I recommend to start using https://testcontainers.org so you can express your IT's with docker images like databases within your tests....